# Eager load partial relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a 1:M relationship between two models. I would like to eager load the last 5 items from the M side inside my 1 side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stmt = session.query(Address).\
                 limit(5).\
                 subquery()
adalias = aliased(Address, stmt)
for user, address in session.query(User, adalias).\
         join(adalias, User.addresses): 
     print user
     print address
```